# HTML5 form validation pattern alphanumeric with spaces?

Tags: regex, html, validation, forms, alphanumeric

I have the following input tag in my html5 form:

```
<p>
    <label>Company Name*</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="field" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" />
</p>
```

This works just fine checking if the company name consists out of alphanumeric characters. But of course I want to allow spaces in the company name. I need to know what I should add to the pattern.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

How about adding a space in the pattern attribute like `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"`.
If you want to support any kind of space try `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+"`

Comment: Just what i was looking for, thanks. Could you explain what the differce is between any kind of space with `\s` and just the ` ` space.

Comment: `\s` is a class containing tab and space characters.

Comment: if i type only spaces,then it accepts.whats should be my pattern which accepts spaces but not if ONLY space is entered?

Comment: This will not work with diacritics, i.e.: `ą, ó, ä, ö`

Comment: @bumerang how could we easily include those?

Comment: @Julix check out my answer bellow

Answer (score 43):

My solution is to cover all the range of diacritics:

```
([A-z0-9À-ž\s]){2,}
```

`A-z` - this is for all latin characters

`0-9` - this is for all digits

`À-ž` - this is for all diacritics

`\s`  - this is for spaces

`{2,}` - string needs to be at least 2 characters long

Comment: that's really neat, never saw that before. -- managed to found it, now that I know what it's called: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30225759/2848941

Very useful, thanks!

Comment: What I had been using before (and it seemed to work, but I don't understand it, was this: [a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u024f ]+

Comment: You can simply use `max-length` and `min-length` attributes instead of using the `{2,}` bit. Regardless I like this answer; especially for the clarifications you took the time to make, +1.

Comment: please don't forget apostrophes. Us Irish take the brunt of this anti apostrophe discrimination!

Comment: @eddyoc Can you then please provide in comment, or in my answer edit necessary characters range?

Comment: @eddyoc or you just mean this sign `'`

Comment: lol, what about Chinese, Cyrillic, Japanese?

Answer (score 11):

It's quite an old question, but in case it could be useful for anyone, starting from a combination of good responses found here, I've ended using this pattern:

```
pattern="([^\s][A-z0-9À-ž\s]+)"
```

It will require at least two characters, making sure it does not start with an empty space but allowing spaces between words, and also allowing special characters such as `ą, ó, ä, ö`.

Answer (score 10):

To avoid an input with only spaces, use: `"[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"`.

```
eg: abc | abc aBc | abc 123 AbC 938234
```

To ensure, for example, that a first AND last name are entered, use a slight variation like

`"[a-zA-Z]+[ ][a-zA-Z]+"`

```
eg: abc def
```

Comment: Or I believe you can just include the 'required' attribute to circumvent that.

Comment: @user1893702 The required attribute will accept spaces. You're Gonna Need a Bigger Regex.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to ensure the user doesn't just enter spaces but a valid name:

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*"
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```html
<h1>In my case, I need only Number and I hafta stop to user entering any Alphabets. We can also stop to entering any number.</h1>

<hr> 
<p>
<h2>Number only</h2>
<input type="tel" name="PhoneNumber" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" />
</p>
<hr> 
<p>
<h2>Alphabets only</h2>
<input type="text" name="name" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^A-z]/g,'');" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like below format code

```
$('#title').keypress(function(event){
    //get envent value       
    var inputValue = event.which;
    // check whitespaces only.
    if(inputValue == 32){
        return true;    
    }
     // check number only.
    if(inputValue == 48 || inputValue == 49 || inputValue == 50 || inputValue == 51 || inputValue == 52 || inputValue == 53 ||  inputValue ==  54 ||  inputValue == 55 || inputValue == 56 || inputValue == 57){
        return true;
    }
    // check special char.
    if(!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 120) && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0)) { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
})
```

Comment: Characters 91 to 96 are special characters. Should be event.preventDefault(); for that range

Answer (score -1):

**Use below code for HTML5 validation pattern alphanumeric without / with space :-**

*for HTML5 validation pattern alphanumeric without space :-*
**onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122 || event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90"**

*for HTML5 validation pattern alphanumeric with space :-*

**onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122 || event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90 || event.charCode == 32"**

Comment: The question seems to be looking for a validation pattern. Also, please note that keyboard event properties like `charCode`, `keyCode`, and `which` will be deprecated and replaced by `key`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key