# How to validate a username field html

Tags: html, pattern-matching

I am trying to validate a username field. The field must have numbers, letters and no special chars.

This pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]" stands for username with numbers and letters.

What the pattern should be?

Comment: I think this solution already answered your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19619457/4420599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern stands for a **single** **uppercase-char, lowercase-char** or **number**.

The pattern you want looks like this:

`/^[a-z\d]+$/i`

Explained:

- `^` - from the start of the string (or line with the **m** flag)
- `[` - start character class
- `a-z` - range of characters from a to z
- `\d` - the same as 0-9 (any digit)
- `]` - close character class
- `+` one or more
- `$` - end of string (or line with the **m** flag)

Then we have the *flags* outside the actual regexp `//` itself.
We're using the `i` flag which stands for case insensitive.

Cheatsheets / Tools

- http://regexr.com/
- http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" onkeyup="if (/[^|a-z0-9]+/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/[^|a-z0-9]+/g,'')">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be done in raw HTML (doubt it), so you'll need some javascript. You can have a function called on the "onchange" attribute if you like, so the element would be like:

```
<input id="username" type="text" onchange="validate()" name="name" value=""/>
```

The javascript function would then just access the element, get the value, and check what is in it, like so:

```
function validate() {
     var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
     //do checking here however you like (regex, iteration, etc.)
}
```

BUT, this needs to be done server side. You can do it client-side if you really want to, but it MUST be done on the server side, in any case. I assume you meant on the client side since you tagged the question with HTML, rather than a server side language.

Answer (score 0):

This should work to test a string for only characters and numbers with javascript.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```