# Disable submit button whenever there is a white space in input tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<form name="regForm">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" ng-model="username" required>
 <button ng-click="submitSignup()" type="submit" ng-disabled=" (regForm.username.$dirty && regForm.username.$invalid) || regForm.username.$pristine">Sign Up</button>
 </form>
```

I want the input field to be invalid and the sign up button disabled whenever one presses white space. I don't want to allow white space in the input field either by typing or by pasting. The sign up button should be disabled whenever there is a white space either by typing or by pasting. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Sounds like you want angular logic that would make the input invalid if there is a space.  This wouldn't require jQuery, so I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use ng-pattern to validate the input and disable the button on invalid pattern.

[Follow that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619428/html5-form-validation-pattern-alphanumeric-with-spaces)

Comment: I've followed that link, and I tried using `pattern="([A-z0-9À-ž])"` but I want it to accept other characters like underscore but not whitespace

Answer (score 1):

the easy way to validate white spaces, is to trim the value of the input.

```
if(regForm.username.trim())
```

This conditional is true is the result is different to empty string.

Regards.